# node.js: database query + multipart form data locks up

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, multipart

I'm still reasonably new to the whole node thingie, so please forgive me if this is rampantly stupid, but:

If I call `query()` on a *node-mysql* client object, I can no longer get the body of a request object from within my web app (*express*).

my basic POST / PUT pattern requests requiring user auth is:

```
_db_client = connect_to_db_server();
app.post("/some/path", function (req, res) {
    _db_client.query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = ?",
                     [ http_basic_auth.username ], function (err, results) {
      if (err != null || resp == null) {
         res.send("AUTH FAILURE: sorry, you can't do that", 403);
      } else {
         get_request_body(req, function (body) {
            do_something();
            res.send("yay, I'm happy", 200);
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Now, the problem is that the get_request_body function simply never comes back. It seems as though it's just "blocked" on teh request object.

Here is a sample program:

```
var express = require('express'),
    mysql = require('mysql');

var MySQLClient = mysql.Client;
var client = new MySQLClient();

client.user = 'root';
client.password = '';

client.connect(function(err, res) {
    client.query("USE Gazelle", function (qerr, qresp) {
    });
});

var app = express.createServer(  );
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post("/test", function (req, res) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM Users', function (err, results) {
        get_request_body(req, function (body) {
            console.log("wooo");
            console.log(body);
            res.send("cool", 200);
        });
    });
});


app.listen(8080);


function get_request_body (req, callback) {
    if (req.rawBody != undefined) {
        callback(req.rawBody);
    } else {
        var data = '';
        req.setEncoding('binary');

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}
```

**The trick**: It only fails if I'm using multipart form POST data, not regular POST data:

```
curl -u un:pw -X POST -d ' { "cat" : "meow" }' http://localhost:8080/test
```

works

```
curl -u un:pw -X POST -F "image_file=@test.jpg" http://localhost:8080/test
```

locks up and never returns. I've seen the same error with *connect-form* and *multipart-js*. Kind of stumped here now.

Am i a complete idiot? Is this not the correct way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by the time you add your `end` listener to the request object, the `end` event has already fired.  You need to add your IO event listeners to the `req` object immediately in the main `app.post` function scope, not in an async callback when your DB query returns. Here's a version with some log statements that show the sequence of events causing this issue.  The `req.emit('end');` at the bottom is just a hack to prove why the request is locking up.  Your `end` event handler never gets called, but synthesizing a duplicate `end` event does allow the request to complete (but the body has not been properly parsed).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer(  );
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post("/test", function (req, res) {
  req.on('data', function(){
    console.log("data fired but your listener is not yet added");
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end fired but your listener is not yet added');
  });
  setTimeout(function() { //Simulating your async DB query
    console.log("setTimeout finished and fired callback");
        get_request_body(req, function (body) {
            console.log("wooo");
            console.log(body);
            res.send("cool", 200);
        });
      }, 50);
});


app.listen(8081);


function get_request_body (req, callback) {
    if (req.rawBody != undefined) {
        console.log('express.bodyParser parsed it already');
        callback(req.rawBody);
    } else {
        console.log('get_request_body going to parse because ' + req.rawBody);
        var data = '';
        req.setEncoding('binary');

        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('get_request_body got data event');
            data += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function() {
            console.log('get_request_body parsed it');
            callback(data);
        });
        req.emit('end');//BUGBUG
    }
}
```